# Сan’t create a user in the Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

**Сan’t create a user in the Firebase Database** pls help or 
tell me a documentation on this question.
Is it right stroke    user_id: cred.user.uid ?

```
  methods: {
    signup(){
      if(this.alias && this.email && this.password){
        this.feedback = null
        this.slug = slugify(this.alias, {
          replacement: '-',
          remove: /[$*_+~.()'"!\-:@]/g,
          lower: true
        })
        let ref = db.collection('users').doc(this.slug)
        ref.get().then(doc => {
          if(doc.exists){
            this.feedback = 'This alias already exists'
          } else {
          // this alias does not yet exists in the db
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
            .then(cred => {
              ref.set({

                alias: this.alias,
                geolocation: null,
                user_id: cred.user.uid
              })
            }).then(() => {
              this.$router.push({ name: 'GMap' })
            })
            .catch(err => {
              this.feedback = err.message
            })
          }
        })
      } else {
        this.feedback = 'Please fill in all fields'
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have to test it, `console.log(cred)` If I was, I would create a new function for the information I would add to the database, it is not good to use it in this way. for example  saveUserDatabase({this.alias,null,cred.user.uid})

Comment: That looks correct. Do you have any error messages in devtools console?

Comment: no, but database not created (

Answer (score 0):

See the solution in the comments below

https://www.udemy.com/course/build-web-apps-with-vuejs-firebase/learn/lecture/10015192#questions/11358100